# Encryption libraries/algorithms supporting decryption of files and content on Android - and - encryption on the server-side (Linux)

Tags: android, linux, encryption

Any ideas what is the best Encryption library to use for Android that support encryption on server-side (Linux)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as long as you use standard cyphers, standard padding schemes/message syntax and standard modes of operation, the library for encrypting/decrypting should not matter ...

if you use AES / PKCS#7 / CBC that should be common enough to be platform independant ...